# How to solve this python error?

Tags: python

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "final.py", line 21, in 
    lpd = LicensePlateDetector(image)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

I am actually running this program in two files first one consisting of this class functions

```
from collections import namedtuple
from skimage.filters import threshold_local
from skimage import segmentation
from skimage import measure
from imutils import perspective
import numpy as np
import imutils
import cv2
LicensePlate = namedtuple("LicensePlateRegion", ["success", "plate", "thresh", "candidates"])
class LicensePlateDetector:
    print("entered class")
    def __init__(self, image, minPlateW=60, minPlateH=20, numChars=7, minCharW=40):
        self.image = image
        self.minPlateW = minPlateW
        self.minPlateH = minPlateH
        self.numChars = numChars
        self.minCharW = minCharW
    def detect(self):
        lpRegions = self.detectPlates()
        for lpRegion in lpRegions:
            lp = self.detectCharacterCandidates(lpRegion)
            if lp.success:
                yield (lp, lpRegion)
    def detectCharacterCandidates(self, region):
        plate = perspective.four_point_transform(self.image, region)
        cv2.imshow("Perspective Transform", imutils.resize(plate, width=400))
        V = cv2.split(cv2.cvtColor(plate, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV))[2]
        T = threshold_local(V, 29, offset=15, method="gaussian")
        thresh = (V > T).astype("uint8") * 255
        thresh = cv2.bitwise_not(thresh)
        plate = imutils.resize(plate, width=400)
        thresh = imutils.resize(thresh, width=400)
        cv2.imshow("Thresh", thresh)
        labels = measure.label(thresh, neighbors=8, background=0)
        charCandidates = np.zeros(thresh.shape, dtype="uint8")
        for label in np.unique(labels):
            if label == 0:
                continue
            labelMask = np.zeros(thresh.shape, dtype="uint8")
            labelMask[labels == label] = 255
            cnts = cv2.findContours(labelMask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
            cnts = cnts[0] if imutils.is_cv2() else cnts[1]
            if len(cnts) > 0:
                c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
                (boxX, boxY, boxW, boxH) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
                aspectRatio = boxW / float(boxH)
                solidity = cv2.contourArea(c) / float(boxW * boxH)
                heightRatio = boxH / float(plate.shape[0])
                keepAspectRatio = aspectRatio < 1.0
                keepSolidity = solidity > 0.15
                keepHeight = heightRatio > 0.4 and heightRatio < 0.95
                if keepAspectRatio and keepSolidity and keepHeight:
                    hull = cv2.convexHull(c)
                    cv2.drawContours(charCandidates, [hull], -1, 255, -1)
        charCandidates = segmentation.clear_border(charCandidates)
        return LicensePlate(success=True, plate=plate, thresh=thresh,candidates=charCandidates)
```

Second file where I use argparse

```
from __future__ import print_function
import LicensePlateDetector
from imutils import paths
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import cv2
print("First line in finalpy")
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--images", required=True, help="path to the images to be classified")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
print("before for loop")
print(args["images"])
for imagePath in (args["images"]):
    image = cv2.imread(args["images"])
    cv2.imshow("image", image)
    cv2.waitKey(0) 
    if image.shape[1] > 640:
        image = imutils.resize(image, width=640)
    print("Now calling LPD")
    lpd = LicensePlateDetector(image)
    print("About to call detect")
    plates = lpd.detect()
    print("Came back from Detect")
    for (i, (lp, lpBox)) in enumerate(plates):
        lpBox = np.array(lpBox).reshape((-1,1,2)).astype(np.int32)
        cv2.drawContours(image, [lpBox], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
        candidates = np.dstack([lp.candidates] * 3)
        thresh = np.dstack([lp.thresh] * 3)
        output = np.vstack([lp.plate, thresh, candidates])
        cv2.imshow("Plate & Candidates #{}".format(i + 1), output)
    cv2.imshow("Image", image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I wrote those and then using cmd I am running command called python final.py -i California1.jpg. Where final.py is name of file consisting second part of code i.e argparse one and California one is a image consisting of number plate

Comment: class should be LicensePlateDetector(object):

Comment: @JohnJosephFernandes no it shouldn't.

Comment: @JohnJosephFernandes If you write it like LicensePlateDetector(object) then you would get an error.

Answer (score 1):

Python is not Java. If you want to access a class, you need to either import it directly, or reference it via the module you did import. So:

```
import LicensePlateDetector
...
lpd = LicensePlateDetector.LicensePlateDetector(image)
```

or

```
from LicensePlateDetector import LicensePlateDetector
...
lpd = LicensePlateDetector(image)
```

This is one reason why PEP8 recommends naming files as `lower_case_with_underscore.py`.